# Impossible to resize a logo (image) in ion-header

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic5

I can't resize my logo inside ion-header and ion-toolbar with Ionic 5, and I don't understand why ...

I've try anything like :

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <img height="44" class="logo-full" alt="mylogo">
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

And :

```
.logo-full{
   content: url("../assets/logo/logo-dark.png");
   height: 44px;
}
```

I have try to resize header and toolbar, remove toolbar but nothing seems to work for me ...

I know that it's simple usually, but with yearly updates, it's difficult to understand ...

Thank's all folks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
ion-toolbar, ion-header .logo-full{
   content: url("http://placekitten.com/301/301");
   width:44px;
   height: 44px;
   border:2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <img class="logo-full" alt="mylogo">
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

for 200 X 44(width)

```css
ion-toolbar, ion-header .logo-full{ 
  content: url("http://placekitten.com/301/301");
  width: 44px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <img class="logo-full" alt="mylogo">
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: Perfect, the image change at scale when I use width instead of height (I don't understand why), but thank you !

Comment: You can try that as well, you can fix the width and keep increasing the height that will work as you desired.

Comment: I just modified the code(2nd snippet) which increases only the height and width remain same.